# Split string, then output the first characters of each element

Tags: php, twig

Database returns me an `initial_string` like `Abc 123 & Yolo thing`. In `twig` template I need to get the first characters of each space-delimited character sequence, so that in result to see `A1Yt`.

I have tried the following:

```
{% set ug = initial_string|split(" ") %}
{% set UG = "" %}
{% for i  in ug  %}
{% set UG += ug[loop.index-1]|first %}
{% endfor %}
{{ UG }}
```

but `twig` does not let me alter `UG` by using `+=`.

How can I solve it then? Doing it on server-side is not an option, only in `twig` template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [the ~ operator](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/templates.html#other-operators) to concatenate two strings:

```
{% set UG = UG ~ ug[loop.index-1]|first %}
```